# How to get a return value of a solidty function in javascript using web3?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

My contract is:

```
   contract changeName{
    string customerName;

    function changeName(string _customerName)
       {
          customerName=_customerName;
       }

    function getName() returns(string)
       {

         return customerName;
       }
    }
```

In Javascript(meteor.js):

```
//contractAddress= block address where contract is deployed
//AbiArray : When contract is compiled 
var myContract= web3.eth.contract(AbiArray).at(contractAddress);

myContract.getName(function(err,res)
{
alert(res);
//getting block address here
//How to get function return value

});
```

Comment: Can you kindly reformat the question using Edit as now it has some formatting errors making it hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

you could define the get function as `constant` and in your js code use :

```
 var contractInstance = MyContract.at('contract_address');
  var variable= contractInstance.getName();
```

Comment: Thank You ! But I'm getting an exception : The metamask web3 object does not support synchronous method like eht_call without  callback parameter.

Comment: Is there any alternative to metamask? I mean how to connect with Ethereum Blockchain without metamask?

Comment: Use mist instead of metamask

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
var contractInstance = MyContract.at('contract_address');
var variable= contractInstance.getName(function(err, res){
    console.log(err); // Error object
    console.log(res); // Result object
    console.log(res.c[0]); // Your "customerName"
});
```